# How do you *properly* query Redis from Tornado?

Tags: twisted, redis, tornado

I'm curious what the recommended method of querying Redis (or any DB for that matter) is from Tornado.

I've seen some examples like https://gist.github.com/357306 but they all appear to be using blocking calls to redis.

My understanding is that to avoid grinding Tornado to a halt, I need to be using non-blocking DB libraries like the ones developed for Twisted.

Am I wrong?  How is this supposed to be done?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**When it comes to blocking commands like BLPOP or listening to a Pub/Sub channel you'll need an asynchronous client like [tornado-redis](https://github.com/leporo/tornado-redis).** You may start with [this demo](https://github.com/leporo/tornado-redis/tree/master/demos/websockets) to see how the [tornado-redis](https://github.com/leporo/tornado-redis) client may be used to develope a simple public chat application.

**But I would recommend using the synchronous [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) client in conjunction with [hiredis](https://github.com/pietern/hiredis-py) for most other cases.**

The main advantage of asynchronous client is that your server can handle incoming requests while waiting for Redis server response. However, the Redis server is so fast that in most cases an overhead of setting up asynchronous callbacks in your Tornado application adds more to the total time of request processing then the time spent on waiting for Redis server response.

Using an asynchronous client you may try to send multiple requests to the Redis server at the same time, but the Redis server is a single-threaded one (just like Tornado server), so it will answer to these requests one-by-one and you'll gain almost nothing. And, in fact, you don't have to send multiple Redis commands at the same time to the same Redis server as long as there are pipelines and commands like MGET/MSET.

An asynchronous client has some advantages when you use several Redis server instances, but I suggest using a synchronous (redis-py) client and a proxy like [twemproxy](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy) or [this one](https://github.com/kni/redis-sharding-hs-strict) (the latter supports pipelining and MGET/MSET commands).

**Also I suggest not to use the connection pooling when using the redis-py client in Tornado applications**. Just create a single `Redis` object instance for each Redis database your application connects to.

Comment: Indeed, using a synchronous client sounds OK for the average case, but  the worst case might not be acceptable!  Example 1: if Redis hangs or network to Redis is slow, you will hang your Tornado app.  Example 2: serializing requests on the client and serializing on the server is only equivalent if network latency is 0, which almost never the case.

Comment: tornado-redis is not maintained anymore. But the repository suggests some alternatives: https://github.com/aio-libs/aioredis and https://github.com/mrjoes/toredis

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend to use [brukva](https://github.com/kmerenkov/brukva) which is an "Asynchronous Redis client that works within Tornado IO loop".

Comment: Just in case anyone stumbles across this post, I think the most up to date async redis library is now tornadoredis https://github.com/leporo/tornado-redis

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the [port of Tornado to Twisted](https://github.com/dustin/tornado) and then use [the Twisted Redis API](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/txredis/) with that.  Tornado itself doesn't seem to have arbitrary asynchronous operations as an objective (though if you wanted to rebuild all of the sorts of things that have been built for Twisted, you probably **could** build them from [the low-level iostream APIs in Tornado](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/iostream.py), but [I wouldn't recommend it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458631/whats-so-cool-about-twisted/5461967#5461967)).

Comment: Or the Twisted reactor implementation on top of Tornado:  http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/twisted.html