# how to do asynchronous writes to redis in tornado

Tags: python, redis, tornado

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953786/how-do-you-properly-query-redis-from-tornado), I am trying out the asynchronous driver `tornado-redis`. From the demo ([Github example](https://github.com/leporo/tornado-redis/blob/master/demos/simple/app.py)), it shows that how to do asynchronous gets using this library, but it is not clear to me that if the sets are asynchronous too (they do have a callback function).

So if possible, what is the correct way of doing asynchronous writes using `tornado-redis`? Would it be something like this:

```
@tornado.web.asynchronous
@tornado.gen.engine
def post(self):
    ...
    yield tornado.gen.Task(t.set,'key', 'value')
```

Comment: What is not clear for you? Code sample in your question looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `tornado-redis` code. `Client.set` method has following defenition:

```
def set(self, key, value, callback=None):
    self.execute_command('SET', key, value, callback=callback)
```

So yes, it takes callback and can be used with `gen.Task`.

Correct ways to write asynchronously:

1. Way you described in question, using `gen`.
2. Way, described in github example.

Example from github:

```
c = tornadoredis.Client()
c.connect()

def on_set(result):
    log.debug("set result: %s" % result)

c.set('foo', 'Lorem ipsum #1', on_set)
c.set('bar', 'Lorem ipsum #2', on_set)
c.set('zar', 'Lorem ipsum #3', on_set)
```

Separate class with gen module:

```
class MyRedisWrapper(object):
    @gen.engine
    def set(self, key, value):
        yield tornado.gen.Task(t.set, key, value)

r = MyRedisWrapper()

class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        r.set('key', 'value') #It will work, but not sure about efficiency.
```

Comment: thanks. Can I use the `gen` approach inside a custom class in an Tornado app, that is, *not* inside a RequestHandler class/subclass. If not, how should I use it asynchronously in such case? By supplying a callback to the get/set methods as in the second option above?

Comment: `gen` is syntactic sugar, so yes. You can use `gen.engine` at any method.

Comment: looking at: http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/gen.html#decorator, to be more precise, `gen.engine` should only be used for an async method. In your  'separate class' example above, the `set` method is not async?

Comment: `t.set` is async. If you will use `gen.Task` on not async method - it will throw argument error, like in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679040/using-gen-task-with-tornado-for-a-simple-function.

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confused, the documentation says 'it doesn’t make sense to use gen.engine on functions that don’t already take a callback argument'. In the example above, what is the callback argument for the `set(self, key, value)` method (`t.set` is different and I presume that by which you mean the `tornadoredis` method).

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `yield gen.Task` with functions that don't take `callback` argument. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how this guideline: '`it doesn’t make sense to use gen.engine on functions that don’t already take a callback argument`' applies to the example above for the `set(self, key, value)` method inside `MyRedisWrapper` class? This method does not have a callback argument, does it? Yet, you're using a `gen.engine` decorator on it.

Comment: When you write simple `get` in request handler - you write `gen.engine` also, but `get` doesn't take `callback` argument. I think, that you shouldn't use `gen.engine` if you only use functions that don't take callback inside decorated method.