# Architecting a multithreaded app with a REST interface

Tags: python, rest, architecture, celery, twisted

I'm working through possible architectures for a problem. In as few words as possible, the problem is: I need to design a system that allows clients to connect using HTTP/REST to kick off long running processes. Each process will create a persistent connection to a third party server and write the received data to a queue. Each process will terminate only if the third party server closes the connection or another HTTP/REST request is received indicating it should be terminated.

**Constraints and background:**

- Clients must be able to connect using HTTP/REST
- System must be written in Python

I'm a lower level C guy (with enough Python experience to feel competent) but trying to wrap my head around the Python frameworks available for making this easier. My gut is to jump into the weeds and I know if I implement this as I'm thinking, I might as well have written it in C. Don't want that. I want to leverage as many frameworks and libraries for Python as possible. Performance is not a top priority.

**Approaches I've considered:**

- In doing research, I came across **Twisted** which might be a fit and seems to make sense to me (thinking about this as a daemon). I'm imagining the final product would be a Twisted app that exposes a REST interface, dispatches new threads connecting to the third party service for each client request received, and would manage its own thread pool. I'm familiar with threading, though admittedly haven't done anything in Python with them yet. In a nutshell, **Twisted** [looks very cool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458631/whats-so-cool-about-twisted), though in the end, I'm left wondering if I'm overcomplicating this.
- The second approach I considered is using **Celery and Flask** and simply let Celery handle all the dispatching, thread management, etc. I found this article showing [Celery and Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/celery/) playing nicely together. It seems much like a much simpler approach.

After writing this, I'm leaning towards the second option of using Celery and Flask, though I don't know much about Celery, so looking for any advice you might have, as well as other possible architectures that I'm not considering. I really appreciate it and thank you in advance.

Comment: To the moderators: What? While I understand that opinion-based questions like "What language is better C# or Java?" or "Where should I put curly braces?" have no place on Stack Overflow, I highly and strongly disagree with the idea this question which asks a reasonable question regarding software architecture fits into the category of opinion-based questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Twisted is overkill here.

From what you described, the combination of Celery and Flask would suffice. It would allow you to implement a REST interface that kicks off your long running processes as Celery tasks. You can easily implement a REST method allowing clients to stop running tasks by invoking Celery's revoke method on a tasks ID. Take note that Celery depends on a Message Broker for sending and receiving messages (frequently RabbitMQ is used) and a data backend for storing results (frequently Redis is used).

```
>>> from celery.task.control import revoke
>>> revoke(task_id, terminate=True)
```

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#revoking-tasks